# Como retornar pesquisa independentemente de acentuação em sistemas Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, acentuação

Estou com um problema em um sistema em relação à pesquisa que não retorna resultado por motivos de acentuação.

Gostaria de saber como faço para que a acentuação seja ignorada no sistema ?

Observação o sistema já esta hospedado e em funcionamento com base de dados SQL Server contendo muitos dados.
Estou utilizando a metodologia Code First, Asp.Net MVC, Entity Frameworks

O Link SQL que estou utilizando é este.

```
var pesquisa = db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Cidade.Contains(cidade) &&
                                (x.Nome.Contains(empresa)
                                || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(empresa))))
                                .ToList();
```

Como faço para o código acima ignore a acentuação juntamente com caixa alta ToUpper()

Comment: Você não disse qual sistema é esse e nem como ou onde essa pesquisa é feita e nem que tipo de pesquisa é essa.  Você só disse qual é o SGBD e quais são as suas bibliotecas, mas não falou nada sobre as suas tabelas, colunas e procedimentos de `SELECT`. Assim, não dá para te dizer como você ignora a acentuação porque nem dá para se dizer onde ou como você colocaria isso. Edite a sua pergunta e acrescente esse tipo de informação.

Answer (score 1):

Se utilizar consultas direto no sql:

```
Select * from tabela where campo like '%texto_om_acento%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Caso queira consultar com linq:

```
var result = from p in People
             where p.Name.ToUpper().Contains(RemoveDiacritics(filter.ToUpper()))
             select p;
```

Comment: Vocês tem toda razão acabei de editar, minha pergunta @MiguelJm e Victor Stafusa daria para você me auxiliar no Linq SQL que postei em minha pergunta editada

Comment: como faço para que esta instrução tenha às configurações de pesquisa sem acentuação e diferenciação ente minusculas e maiúsculas:

var pesquisa = db.Empresa.Where(x => x.Cidade.Contains(cidade) &&
                                (x.Nome.Contains(empresa)
                                || x.CategoriaEmpresa.Any(c => c.Categoria.Nome.Contains(empresa))))
                                .ToList();